# Keep a thread running in background even after parent is not alive in Win Ui 3, C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winui-3

I want to keep a local server running even after main window or main thread is closed.

things i tried:

```
    internal class IpHandler
    {
        Socket socket;

        public IpHandler(Socket _socket)
        {
            socket = _socket;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Initiating; Recviced socket: {socket.AddressFamily}");
            Thread tt = new Thread(new ThreadStart(initiateServer));
            tt.IsBackground = true;// !!!
            tt.Start();
        }

        async void initiateServer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Receive message.
                    var buffer = new byte[1_024];
                    var received = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
                    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);

                    var eom = "<END>";
                    if (response.IndexOf(eom) > -1 /* is end of message */)
                    {
                        processCommand(response.Replace(eom, ""));
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error Handled: {se.Message}");
                    break;

                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException ode)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Disconnected Handled: {ode.Message}");
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
  }
```

Even after [Thread.IsBackground](https://stackoverflow.com) is set to `true`, When i close the App by clicking on ( X ) the server thread is terminated and socket connection is lost.

And yes, I thoroughly searched processes in `Task Manager` and it wasn't there.

My Configuration:

```
Framework: Win Ui 3,
SDK: 1.1.5,
language: C#
Windows 11
```

How can i keep a thread(server) running even after main or ui thread is stopped in Win Ui 3 ?

Comment: `Even after Thread.IsBackground is set to true` - That's the opposite from what you want. You want to set that to `false`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Just tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to start a new process instead of a thread?

Comment: You should probably add a `catch (Exception ex){Debug.WriteLine(...);}` to the end of your catch blocks, because you currently won't get any output if, say, an `InvalidOperationException` gets thrown in the loop.

Comment: @McNets has the right answer. Your server logic needs to be a separate Process, not a Thread.

Comment: @McNets @Chaos can you give me an example, I mean to start a thread we do `Thread(new ThreadStart(funcName)).start()` but i can't find any example for 'process' to achive same functionality